# Can I operate whole investing and trading in US stock exchange staying outside USA?

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets, non-resident

My sister has just gone to USA and will try to settle down. She wants to invest some money in US stock exchange. But she hardly have any idea of stock market. Now she wants me to operate her investing and regular trading through online staying in my country Bangladesh, just beside India.
Now my questions are:

1. Can I really do all the trading, analysing, valuation and management through online staying outside USA?
2. Is it possible to get real time / current market news (all) from online sources to analyze and evaluate current and potential companies?

Comment: Are you asking about setting this up or just operating it? If your sister is in the US and has all the necessary paperwork, she can quite easily set it up. If she is comfortable giving you the credentials for her online account, then there is nothing stopping you doing that from anywhere with a reasonable internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable info Mr. Peter K. My main concern whether I can get all the current quick market news to analyze my trading policy through online sources. Hows about that??

Comment: Most online trading sites give reasonably quick market news.  Sometimes the "real-time" option is only available for "premium" users.  The non-premium option is usually about a 15 minute delay. I use ETrade and have their real-time option.

Comment: You probably don't want a trading strategy based on real-time news where small time differences matter; as a human you are very unlikely to beat the computers on Wall St. at the real-time game.  A strategy based on thoughtful, deliberate reflection about long-term fundamentals is more likely to fit your trading bandwidth.

Comment: The time zones could also make a real-time trading strategy disruptive to your sleep.

Answer (score 2):

In short: **yes, as long as you have Internet access.**
See, for example [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/53647/i-need-to-open-a-brokerage-account-in-the-us-from-australia) or [this one](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39072/how-can-i-invest-money-in-stocks-via-usa-broker-while-being-a-citizen-of-ukrain) about opening a brokerage account from outside the US.  Your sister could even open an account here in the US and provide you with access.
However, I'm guessing you're not a registered or even formally trained financial advisor and if you make bets with her money that don't work out well, she could get pretty upset with you.   You might consider doing research from Bangladesh on good financial advisors and picking one (or a few) to recommend she go see in the US.

EDIT: OP hopes to be a financial advisor in the future. Given that comment, I'd recommend looking into becoming a Certified Financial Planner (unless CFA suits your goals; you indicated that process is already underway), as a step towards that goal.  Information about the certification in the US is [here](http://www.cfp.net/become-a-cfp-professional), in India [here](http://www.fpsbindia.org/scripts/CFPCertification.aspx), and in some other countries [here](https://www.fpsb.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. You are right, I am very amateur. However, I have a bachelor degree in Finance. Moreover, I am taking preparation to sit for CFA part 1. In addition to these, I have been participating trading game on market watch site for last couple of months. My goal is to be a regular investor in US stock market. I want to be a professional in this field. That's why I am thinking of starting with my sister's investment. But if you think otherwise then please give me a proper direction, so that I can reach to my goal. Thanks again.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think; it matters much more what your sister thinks. Also see new paragraph in answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes many people operate accounts in usa from outside usa.
You need a brokerage account opened in the name of your sister and then her username and password.
Remember that brokerages may check the location of login and may ask security questions before login. So when your sister opens her account , please get the security questions.
Also note that usa markets open ( 7.00 pm or 8.00 pm IST depending on daylight savings in usa). So this means when they close at 4:00 pm ET, it will be 1:30 or 2:30 am in India. This means it will affect your sleeping hours if you intend to day trade.
Also understand that there are some day trading restrictions and balances associate. Normally brokerages need 25,000 $ for you to be a day trader.
Finally CFA is not a qualification to be a trader and desire to become a trader doesn't make one a trader. TO give an analogy , just because you want to be a cricketer doesn't make you one. It needs a lot of practice and discipline.Also since in bangladesh , you will always convert the usa amount to bangladeshi currency and think of profits and losses in those terms. This might actually be bad.

- Regards
  Trader